# What is :array for in - private static function name():array

Tags: php, phpstorm

I know this will have been answered before but don't know what terminology to use when searching...

PhpStorm just set up a method for me and added `:array` to the end of the declaration line, for example,

```
private static function name():array
```

Never seen `:array` before - what's that all about? Is it to do with return?

Cheers!

Comment: PHP 7 now allows for return type declarations, see: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: Nice and easy, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is PHP 7 return type declaration. You can learn more about return type declaration on [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration):

> PHP 7 adds support for return type declarations. Similarly to [argument type declarations](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration), return type declarations specify the type of the value that will be returned from a function. The same [types](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.types) are available for return type declarations as are available for argument type declarations.
>
> [Strict typing](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration.strict) also has an effect on return type declarations. In the default weak mode, returned values will be coerced to the correct type if they are not already of that type. In strong mode, the returned value must be of the correct type, otherwise a [TypeError](http://php.net/manual/en/class.typeerror.php) will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks, although I found the link in cteski's comment on my original question more useful.